# Blur div css issue

Tags: css

I have a div that has transparent background-color. I want to blur its background color so the transparent color is blurred and the text on the div is more easy to see.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you post your HTML so I can make you a sample on your actual page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't blur a color. That wouldn't do anything.

What I think you'd want to do is add a `text-shadow` enough that the text is blurred and maybe darken the background. Try this:

```
#not-selected {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #<slightly darker text color>;
}

#text-background {
  background-color: #<a little darker>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't have the ability to blur, you can however, [simulate the effect](http://css-tricks.com/1820-blurry-background-effect/) using background images.

Also, you may want to look into [filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but these only work in IE.